# document is not defined in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to build a website including HTML, CSS and JS.

I have a HTML file and a JS file. I am trying to give the values of the HTML file to the JS file by using `document.getElementById();` but it wont work.

This problem kinda holds me back and I am stuck because of that.

```
var b = document.getElementById("radioYes"); // a radio button called "yes"
var d = document.getElementById("radioNo"); // a radio button called "no"
var c = document.getElementById("submit1"); // submit-button
```

What can I do?

Comment: `document` global object is avilable when your JS is being executed in browser, otherwise not. Node will not have this.

Comment: how do I execute my JS in the browser?

Comment: @SlimE - I suggest working through some basic web programming tutorials, they'll help you understand where the various pieces go, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Where are you running your js file?

The document object is only available in the browser, and not in the node environment.  Try opening your html file in the browser - make sure you add your js script to the html file.

Have a look at this answer: [Using Document object in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748996/using-document-object-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't have a default `document` global. *Browsers* provide one, but your Node.js code doesn't run in a browser, it runs in the Node.js environment (e.g., as an application on your workstation, or as a server process, etc.).

To run the code you've shown, you'd include your `.js` file in a page by using a `script` tag in the HTML, typically at the end of `body` just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script src="filename.js"></script>
</body>
```

Then you'd use a web server process (perhaps Node.js itself, perhaps using [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com) or [Koa](http://koajs.com) though you don't have to) or similar to provide that page in response to a request.

Comment: Hi, I added my "<script src="app.js"></script>" but still am getting "document is not defined"