# Add new/replace element in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

My requirement is after clicking on some  button, I need to create a new and replace element something we do with DOM manipulation such as createElement,replaceChild. How we can achieve this with the combination of vanilla JS and Node Js?

Based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32126003/node-js-document-is-not-defined) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51919623/document-is-not-defined-in-nodejs/51919669) I know DOCUMENT is not supported in NodeJs, but how I have to do below code with the help of Node and JS?

I am trying to replace below label with another element but not sure how to achieve this using nodejs.

```
<label id="task1Status" class="progressDiv progress">Yet to Start</label>
```

with below JS code,

```
let loadingE=document.createElement('div');
console.error("replace1");
loadingE.className='lds-ellipsis';
let loadingE1=document.createElement('div');
let loadingE2=document.createElement('div');
let loadingE3=document.createElement('div');
let loadingE4=document.createElement('div');
loadingE.appendChild(loadingE1);
loadingE.appendChild(loadingE2);
loadingE.appendChild(loadingE3);
loadingE.appendChild(loadingE4);
OldE=document.getElementById('task1Status');
document.getElementById('divTask1Status').replaceChild(loadingE,OldE);
```

Comment: NodeJS is a server-side language. It doesn't have the `window` property, because it is not contained within a window. NodeJS is normally contained within a `module`. To achieve such behavior, which I believe takes place solely on the client-side, you should use pure JavaScript

Comment: If you need to do server-side html manipulation you would need to use a library like JSDOM that can parse html and provide dom manipulation api

Comment: @PatrickEvans I think he's talking about DOM manipulation after page load.