# How to format the phoneNumber without using HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, phone-number, cleave

I am using Cleave.js with Node.js. Here I am getting `document not defined` error. How to resolve this issue?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var document = require('html-element').document;
var Cleave = require('cleave.js');
require('cleave.js/dist/addons/cleave-phone.in');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
var input = document.createElement('input')
input.value =  'XXXXXXXXXX' 
const cleave = new Cleave('input', { phone: true, phoneRegionCode: 'in'
});
res.send('Hello World! ' + input.value);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Requirement: I will call this API from another microservice (Java) along with the phone numbers. From this I need result formatted phonenumber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format phone number, one can use **awesome-phonenumber** npm module.

```
const PhoneNumber = require('awesome-phonenumber');
const str = "+919090989790";
const pn = new PhoneNumber(str);
```

Validate phone number using predefined functions like:
**pn.isValid() && pn.isMobile()**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) as in nodejs context there is no `document` nor `window` object defined.

[related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748996/using-document-object-in-nodejs)

Comment: Thank you. I tried . But am not able to get the value.