# Load data to Snowflake using NodeJS/Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jsdom

I have a simple HTML with single button. JavaScript (being client-side script) captures time of each click. I got stuck on how to pass event/time occurence of a `click` and display using Node.js to later transfer it intoo Snowflake database.

From what I reviewed it seems that workaround is `JSDOM` however currently it throws me an error.

Here are the topics I reviewed:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming`

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38748996/using-document-object-in-nodejs`

[UPDATE - November 2020]

After reviewing below I came up with new code splitting the project into 3 files. Still need help with inserting data into Snowflake, not sure how to bind click event to the sql text. Overall goal is to insert datetime of click event into Snowflake's table:

`https://gist.github.com/aerrity/fd393e5511106420fba0c9602cc05d35`

Work in progress code:

**server.js**

```
console.log('Server-side code running');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// serve files from the public directory
app.use(express.static('public'));



//connect to snowflake and load data
var snowflake = require('snowflake-sdk');
var connection = snowflake.createConnection( {
    account: 'xxxx',
    username: 'xxxx',
    password: 'xxxx'
    }
    );

//confirm connection is working
connection.connect(
        function(err, conn) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Unable to connect: ' + err.message);
                }
            else {
                console.log('Successfully connected to Snowflake.');
                // Optional: store the connection ID.
                connection_ID = conn.getId();
                }
            }
        );


// start the express web server listening on 8080
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('listening on 8080');
});

// serve the homepage
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/countClicks.html');
});



// insert data into snowflake isues, how to bind click event?
connection.execute({
  sqlText: 'INSERT INTO DEMO_DB.PUBLIC.INPUT_NODEJS(CLICK_DATETIME)',
  binds: [/clicked]
});
```

**countClicks.js**

```
const button = document.getElementById('clicks');
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('button was clicked');

  fetch('/clicked', {method: 'POST'})
    .then(function(response) {
      if(response.ok) {
        console.log('Click was recorded');
        return;
      }
      throw new Error('Request failed.');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

**countClicks.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Node + Express + Snowflake example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Node + Express + Snowflake example</h1>
    <p id="counter">Loading button click data.</p>
    <button id="myButton">Click me!</button>
  </body>
  <script src="countClicks.js"></script>
</html>
```